# Is there any way to get the resolvers object of a graphql schema

Tags: neo4j, graphql, graphql-js

I am autogenerating a schema in neo4j graphql library and it's also creating the resolvers for me, so my simple question is `Is there a way to get resolvers from a graphql schema`.

I tried finding a method for that , also googled it but couldn't reach to any satisfying answer.

Answer (score 0):

The neo4j GraphQL library is [open source](https://github.com/neo4j/graphql). You can find the code for its built-in resolvers in [this directory](https://github.com/neo4j/graphql). You can also write your own [custom resolvers](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/custom-resolvers/).